# Jersey - Maven (Quickstart) Project for Client

Tags: rest, maven, jersey

I just found a command for creating the core service:

```
  mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://download.java.net/maven/2
```

Is there any maven command for creating explicit a jersey client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - but the jersey archetypes do have the client code in the test that is automatically included in the generated project.